# Umbraco XSLT search page navigation using input onchange

Tags: forms, xslt, pagination, umbraco, onchange

I have created a pagination input that on change will go to the value entered into the input.

[image]

It will detect the page range and allow navigation between those pages in that range.
e.g **/image-gallery-album-1.aspx?page=3**

```
<form type="get" onchange="return false">
  <div class="pagerUI">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr> 
        <!-- previous page -->
        <xsl:if test="$page &gt; 1">
          <td class="pager-prev"><a class="previous" href="{concat('?page=', $page - 1, $qs)}" title="Previous page">&#8249;</a></td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td>Page</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="page" id="page" min="1" >
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$page=1">
              <xsl:attribute name="value">1</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:attribute name="value"> <xsl:value-of select="$currentPageNumber" /> </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:attribute name="max"> <xsl:value-of select="$numberOfPages"/> </xsl:attribute>
          </input></td>
        <td>of <xsl:value-of select="$numberOfPages"/></td>
        <!-- next page -->
        <xsl:if test="$page * $resultsPerPage &lt; count($matchedNodes)">
          <td class="pager-next"><a class="next" href="{concat('?page=', $page + 1, $qs)}" title="Next page">&#8250;</a></td>
        </xsl:if>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

However, when I added this to the XSLTSearch code it doesn't work as the URL loses the search string.

So instead of navigating to: **/image-search.aspx?search=football&page=3**

It navigates to: **/image-search.aspx?page=3** Which doesn't display any results on that page as it's missing the search criteria to display the search results.

I tried to change the form and include an "action" that would change the URL to include the search value but I can't include the input value as it's dynamic.

For example with the below form if I enter any value into the input the URL updates to following: **/image-search.aspx?search=otbra&page=** It's missing the entered number of the input value.

Search form with onchange and action and method post attributes:

```
<form type="get" onchange="return false">
  <xsl:attribute name="method"> <xsl:text>post</xsl:text> </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="action"> <xsl:text>?search=</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="$search"/><xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>page= (input value)</xsl:attribute>
```

Is there some javascript or some way of detecting the value submitted and parsing it into the search string of the URL?

Any assistance would be appreciated. Cheers, JV

Comment: It looks like there should be an XSLT variable called "qs" that should contain all of the search etc, can you post the code where that's being populated from your XSLT file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NOTE: As comment on your post says the likely issue is with the $qs variable, however here's an explanation of how you can get Query String values in Umbraco, for reference.*

---

In Umbraco you can retrieve a Query string value in XSLT using `umbraco.library`

So to retrieve the value of search you would call something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="searchValue" select="umbraco.library:RequestQueryString('search')"/>
```

This creates a variable called searchValue which you can then use to re-inject the query string value in your url.

Something like this:

```
<a class="next" href="{concat('?page=', $page + 1, '&amp;search=', $searchValue)}" title="Next page">&#8250;</a>
```

[More information on umbraco.library](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary) can be found on the [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org/) site.